# jquery template plugin - using {{if}} statement in {{each}}

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I use jquery template plugin and want to do some checks inside {{each}} element.
I want to check if current value equal to value from outer scope, for example something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        {{each Pages}}
            {{if $value == $data.CurrentPage}}
                ${$value}
            {{else}}
                <a href="#">${$value}</a>
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

but I all pages display as links, so $value == $data.CurrentPage never equal to true. I checked that I have one value, when current page number equals to $value, but it also displays as link, it's not expected.
Am I missed something, or this is not possible at all?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

When you use jquery template, it's allow you check conditional in clause is true or false. You can not check conditional using equal clause. Example:

```
 {{if $value}}
     <span>TRUE</span>
 {{else}}
     <span>FALSE</span>
 {{/if}}
```

In this case $value has boolean value.
Hope usefull!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JQuery Template. I achievedthis  like below code for Boolean value.

{{if IS_SELECTED}}

TRUE

{{else}}

FALSE

{{/if}}

Hope useful!!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this and it works fine:

```
{{if Pages != null}}
    {{each Pages }}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            {{if $value.Id == 1}}
                ID = 1
            {{/if}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

**UPD:**
Or you could write your own function `compareWithCurrentPage` which will compare elements and returns true/false

```
{{if Pages != null}}
    {{each Pages }}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            {{if $compareWithCurrentPage($value)}}
                ${$value}
            {{/if}}
            {{else}}
                <a href="#">${$value}</a>
            {{/else}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```